# Как нарисовать фигуру, состоящую из массива шестиугольников?

Tags: java, hex

Я работаю с библиотекой HexGrig на Java (https://github.com/gojuno/hexgrid-java).

У меня есть массив объектов - Hexagon hexagons[]. Я могу получить массив точек вершин каждого с помощью

```
Point[] = grid.hexCorners(hexagons[i]);
```

Имеется метод drawShape у Map, принимающий массив координат в определённом порядке и рисующий на основе этого фигуру - работает это так: он от первой точки проводит линию ко второй, от второй к третьей и тд, от последней - к первой.

Задача - нарисовать фигуру, состоящую из заданных шестиугольников, при этом линии внутри фигуры не нужны, только контур.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать?

Идей реализации у меня нет вообще никаких, а думал я достаточно долго над этим. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Я пробовал выдать каждой точке свои собственные координаты, основанные на координатах шестиугольника, но ничего путного из этого не вышло - не хватает мозгов у меня, чтобы всё обдумать.

Comment: фигуры все будут цельными и дыр в них не будет

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/144921/ ?

Comment: Приведите пример входных данных и соответствующий результат. Пока непонятно, что вам нужно.